# Open graph stories with user generated content possible?

Tags: facebook

Reading through the FB documentation I'm not sure how to approach this or if it is even possible with open graph.

I'm looking to create a story for a iOS app that will post an image taken by the user, along with title and description written by the user. This will deep link back into the app. Looking at the open graph documentation it looks like that is meant only for known and public accessible content. For example books read, movies watched, achievements earned for games etc.

Can I create user driven posts with open graph, or is it really the Graph API I should be looking at?

Main goal is too keep the content private and only viewable to those users the content has been shared with. Seems any open graph solution would make posts accessible by visiting a og: page with the right variables, no auth needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't totally understand everything you are asking (and I'm pretty new to all of this too) but here's a link on how to have a user post an image and message. You do need an auth though.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/adding-photos-to-stories/

Comment: On this page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/overview/. It states open graph stories the object is public information. But if the object is user generated like an image so instagram style, how is that part of the object kept private? I see the action have privacy settings, but it seems the object should have some sort of security as well.

Comment: So the only confusing part about open graphs for me is the OG webpage that you need to host as it shows in this doc. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/web/tutorials/scrumptious/open-graph-object/ It's confusing to me to have private data that needs a publicly accessible webpage. How would this be done for a simple object type with user generated photo and text, keeping in mind the story is pretty much all dynamic content.

Comment: NM Think i found it: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-object-api/